# Is it correct to ask "In which bank you deposit your money"?

Tags: grammar, questions

I want to ask person , where does he deposit the money

> In which bank you deposit your money.

Also, I want to check following

> form which bank are you going to withdraw money.

are these correct sentences. I feel something wrong with it, But I am not quite getting it.

Comment: In which bank **do** you deposit your money?

Comment: "from which bank do you withdraw your money" do you think this also grammatically correct

Comment: @nnnnnn do you think "In which bank you deposit your money?" is wrong ?

Comment: @Cardinal - Yes, it needs the "do" that I highlighted in my previous comment. Kitis - That seems OK grammatically (don't forget a question mark at the end), but I would be more likely to say something like "At which bank is your account?" - asking about the account covers deposits and withdrawals (for most people).

Comment: @Sina, Which bank do you deposit your money in? , this looks great!.when reading it it fells nice. I had the feeling of something wrong in my sentence.

Comment: @Sina - A lot of English speakers have been taught *not* to end a sentence with a preposition, but really it is fine to do so (and your examples sound fine).

Comment: @cardinal, thanks for your answer as well, actually what I want to ask is what you have explained in your comment. thanks lot guys for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: @nnnnnn My question was due to the fact that w-questions can be used without auxiliary verbs. Does this have anything with Preposition **in** ?

Comment: @Kltis I should apologize you for my typo. Let me correct it here. It is correct to start your question with a preposition but it's mainly recommended using it at the end of your question in informal English, as far as I know. So better say: Which bank do you deposit your money in? Which bank are you going to withdraw money from? But write In which bank..., From which...

Comment: @Klits To compelete my apology, I'd like to provide you by this link to learn more about preposition in questions http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say as follows:

In which bank do you deposit your money?

Which bank do you deposit your money in?

Who do you bank with?

Where do you bank?

Comment: I'd put an asterisk on "Which bank do you deposit your money in?" as there is debate over whether it is proper to end an English sentence with a preposition.